# Excel transpose formula Vectical to Horizontal

Tags: excel, transpose

I need little help here please.

I want to transpose this on Excel:

```
Name1        
address1   
tel1   
<empty cel>   
Name2        
address2  
tel2   
<empty cel>   
Name3        
address3  
tel3   
<empty cel>
```

to:

```
Name1        address1           tel1   
Name2        address2           tel2   
Name3        address3           tel3
```

I know this must be easy I have done some tests but I cant... I have Stack overflow

Comment: anyone else can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-1)*4,0)
```

Copy this both across and downwards:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer but it gives me error ... I m using Excel 2013...any other help please??